# Can only squat extremely narrow

Tags: strength, squats, stretching, flexibility, mobility

I'm having a lot of trouble working on my (high-bar) squat. The only way I'm able to squat to proper depth right now is with a hip wide stance, with toes pointed out very far (45 degree or even more). When I try to squat with a wider stance, I feel pain inside my hip. I'm not able to squat to parallel with a shoulder width stance.

I have already performed stretches for my hip flexors and hamstrings, but this doesn't feel like it's helping with the problem.

I tried to do this kneeling frog squat stretch and this also hurts, when spreading the legs more than hip wide. 
[image]

Is this stretch a good way to improve my hip mobility?
Are there any other good stretches that I can try?

Comment: When you squat with a narrow stance to full depth, how do your knees track? Do they track over your toes, or do they bow inwards? Also, are you able to keep your back completely flat with a narrow stance (If not sure, get someone to either film or take a picture for you).

Comment: There are loads of muscles around the hips that are used in the squat, any of them could be restricting you, without a video it is impossible to tell.

Comment: I understand, I will try to make a Video tomorrow. With a narrow stance I can hit parallel depth with a straight back. But only when pointing my feet pretty far out. Everything with a parallel like feet angle is not possible for me atm.

Comment: You should check out some of the hip stretching videos elliott hulse has made over the years, very useful information.

Comment: I kinda forgot about this question in the past few weeks, but I was trying to solve my problem. I'm now doing hip mobility drills, from mobility WOD, almost every day and the pain while squatting is really getting better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone's hip mobility is a little bit different. The only thing that should change between your low and high bar squats is the bar position and torso lean. Unless you are specifically squatting with a different stance as in its programmed in as a squat variation. Mobility work will help you change your stance width but generally a more natural approach of wherever your feet feel most comfortable is usually best in my opinion.

If you are hell bent on getting your stance in though I always felt like breathing pause squats helped me with hitting depth when I had a closer stance.